# Subscriptions - allow users to switch off auto-renew for their subscriptions

Tags: subscriptions

Is it possible to allow a user to 'switch off' auto-renew for their subscription so it expires automatically at the end of the current period?

For example, say a user is 6 months in to a 12 month subscription and they want to stay until the end of that 12 months, but they don't want their subscription to be renewed at the end of the 12 months. Is that possible?

Comment: Hi Pete, can you let us know what module you are using for your subscriptions? Is this Expresso by any chance??

Comment: Sorry, it's the DevDemon Subscriptions module - http://www.devdemon.com/expressionengine-addons/subscriptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just realised this can be done easily by setting the cancel_now parameter of the {exp:subs:cancel} tag to 'no'. In fact this is the default behaviour!

Comment: +1 for working it out :) Dont forget to mark your answer as 'the' answer so others can find it if they are stuck!

Comment: Thanks, I will.  I won't let me do that for another 2 days.

Comment: Ahhh, I never knew that was a limitation!! I shall mention this in the Meta exchange. In that case welcome to the exchange Pete!

Answer (score 0):

FYI - there is actually a way to have auto-renew disabled at the time of signup.

You can put an input in your form like this:

```
<select name="auto_renew">
  <option value="yes">Please Auto-Renew Annually</option>
  <option value="no">Do Not Auto-Renew</option>
</select>
```

The **auto_renew** option is not documented, but it will create the subscription and have it marked to not auto renew after the first payment.

I stumbled onto this because I realized that some people wanted to pay their subscription manually every month, but without knowing the **auto_renew** option, every time they'd "renew" it, auto renewal would be turned back on, so they'd have to "Cancel" each time.